# How to install Git GUI on my local machine that runs on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit OS?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, repository, git, clone

I'm running **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit OS** on my local machine. I want to setup/install Git GUI on this machine. Then I'm having one repository at GitLab that I need to make clone of on my machine, then I should be able to do normal git operations like pull, push, commit, etc. with Git GUI.

Can someone please provide me step by step instructions from installing this Git GUI on my machine to execute normal Git operations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install it with apt-get tool:

```
sudo apt-get install git-gui
```

To run the app use the command:

```
git gui
```

Then, from Repository tab chose Clone and enter "Source Location" and "Target Directory" information and just click on the clone button.